# ¿Como remuevo la linea que aparece por defecto en los elementos entry de un archivo XAML en xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xaml

Actualmente estoy por terminar una aplicación y en algunas ventanas uso elementos de tipo Entry, la cuestión es que esos entrys tienen una linea negra que no puedo quitar, en teoría ya hice la parte de renderizar uno nuevo.

Archivo de renderizacion:

```
namespace AppAdminDipo.Renderers
{
    public class BorderlessEntry: Entry
    {
    }
}
```

importo el archivo

```
 xmlns:renderers="clr-namespace:AppAdminDipo.Renderers"
```

Mando llamar la clase:

```
<renderers:BorderlessEntry
                            FontSize="20"
                            ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
                            Keyboard="Email"
                            Placeholder="Usuario"
                             x:Name="Nick"
                                        
                                        BackgroundColor="#dcebfe"
                            TextColor="#484848" />
```

Pero aun así con esos pasos me muestra la linea negra en mis entry, toma un diseño diferente pero esa linea negra no desaparece.

Comment: quieres borrar el borde de los entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código que estas utilizando solo hereda el Entry tal cual como viene prefabricado. Para generar un Entry personalizado debes seguir lo que indica la documentación de microsoft: [Custom Renderer - Entry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry)

Una vez entiendas como funcionan los Custom Renderers, en android, al definir el evento `OnElementChanged`:

```
Control.Background = new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
```

Para iOS, en el mismo evento `OnElementChanged`:

```
Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.None; Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
```